# EF 6.4 code-first and SQL Server compatibility level

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

The queries generated by EF 6.4 in the application run faster against SQL Server database with compatibility level 100 compared to a database with level 130 or 140. Cannot find any configuration inside the app that targets specific version of SQL Server for generating queries. In theory, the higher the compatibility level is, the better the query optimizer works.

Any ideas why EF 6.4 code-first targets SQL Server compatibility level 100 by default?

Comment: EF does not target a specific compat level, but some queries may run differently with a different compat level.

Comment: You are right that higher compatibility levels should provide better performance in theory but this is not always the case in practice. The most common issue is the db compat level determines the default cardinally estimator. One can configure the cardinality estimator independently of the compat level with ['SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql) in cases where performance regresses with the default one.